# Table Parse query doesn't appear

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I made a table view controller for query object of clouds, the code goes well, but the problem is that when the view load parse query don't shows on the table.

I tried some solution but most of the solutions are for USER class not for any other custom classes.

```
@IBOutlet weak var cloudsTable: UITableView!

var clouds: [PFObject] = [PFObject] ()

func loadClouds () {

    let cloudsQuery = PFQuery(className: "_Clouds")
    cloudsQuery.order(byAscending: "createdAt")

    cloudsQuery.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (result, error) in


        if error == nil
        {
            self.clouds = result!
            self.cloudsTable.reloadData()
            print(self.clouds)
        }
    })
}
```

This function is for calling Clouds class for retrieve value to view

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return clouds.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cloudsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        let userObject:PFObject = clouds[indexPath.row]

        cloudsCell.textLabel?.text = userObject.object(forKey: "user") as? String

        return cloudsCell

    }
```

This for passing parse query to table functions.

Comment: Are `cloudsTable.delegate` & `cloudsTable.datasource` set? You should call `reloadData()` in main thread.

Comment: @Larme No I didn't set them, you mean do I have to set cloudsTable.delegate and cloudsTable.datasource on subclass ? or on view did load function ?

Comment: If you use Storyboard, you can do it there.

Comment: I had connected table delegate and datasource on storyboard. I GOT this error, classnames can only have alphanumeric characters and _, and must start with an alpha character " UserInfo={code=103, temporary=0,

Comment: Add `DispatchQueue.main.async{ self.cloudsTable.reloadData() }`

Comment: where should I add it?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following. I'v edited your code slightly.

Make sure you have your `delegate` and `datasource` set. In your case to your cloud outlet.

[image]

```
@IBOutlet weak var cloudsTable: UITableView!

var clouds = [PFObject]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
          loadClouds()
}

func loadClouds () {
        clouds.removeAll()
        let cloudsQuery = PFQuery(className: "Clouds") //Make sure class name is correct
        cloudsQuery.order(byAscending: "createdAt")
        cloudsQuery.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (result, error) in
            if error == nil
            {
                self.clouds = result!
                self.cloudsTable.reloadData()
                print(self.clouds)
            }
        })
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
} 


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return clouds.count

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let cloudsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

            var recClass = PFObject(className:  "Clouds")
                recClass = clouds[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

                cloudsCell.textLabel?.text = recClass["user"] as? String

                return cloudsCell
}
```

Comment: I'm still having the same error again , here the error message : Invalid classname: _Clouds, classnames can only have alphanumeric characters and _, and must start with an alpha character  (Code: 103, Version: 1.14.2)
Error Domain=Parse Code=103 "Invalid classname: _Clouds, classnames can only have alphanumeric characters and _, and must start with an alpha character " UserInfo={code=103, temporary=0, error=Invalid classname: _Clouds, classnames can only have alphanumeric characters and _, and must start with an alpha character

Comment: this is becasue the class name is wrong! I commented it in the code for you to check.

Comment: should just be Clouds. But go check the scheama to make sure

Comment: The mongoDB scheama. Or in your parse-dashboard

Comment: I change class name from _Clouds to Clouds, and the compiler print the results, but still not showing on table view, I connected delegate and datasource with the table, but I don't know why it didn't show on screen?

Comment: Set the identifier then in the storyboard to "Cell".  And you sure the class is a UITableViewController ?

Comment: I found the solution man, thanks for your help, god please you my friend.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the **PFQueryTableViewController** to load parse query data into a table. Parse understands that querying and loading data into a table is a popular feature and they've created a very simple class that handles this. Check out the guide below and look for **PFQueryTableViewController**. It handles everything from data loading/reloading/cacheing so it's worth a look. If you have any questions on how to implement it, let me know.

https://parseplatform.github.io/docs/ios/guide/